# Problem to build riscv toolchain on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, riscv

I'm starting to use Linux and I need to install a `risc-v toolchain`. I'm following this (https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulp-riscv-gnu-toolchain), but the make command returns the error 127. The last steps I did were:

```sh
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/Bruna/riscv --with-arch=rv32imc --with-cmodel=medlow --enable-multilib
$ make
```

Could someone give me the steps I should follow to solve this problem? Thank you  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCnnj.png)

Comment: Did you install all Prerequisites ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the `git submodule update --init --recursive`?. Submodules source (riscv-binutils-gdb) seems missing.

Answer (score 0):

try this version for integer riscv, I try it already and passed
git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain
git checkout 411d134
git submodule update --init --recursive
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/opt/riscv32i --with-arch=rv32i --with-abi=ilp32
make -j8

if your riscv have mul/div module, add M standard extension
../configure --prefix=/opt/riscv32im --with-arch=rv32im --with-abi=ilp32

if your riscv is 64 bits integer core
../configure --prefix=/opt/riscv64i --with-arch=riscv64i --with-abi=lp64

select option that you want to build:
"M" Standard Extension for Integer Multiplication and Divison
"A" Standard Extension for Atomic Instructions
"F" Standard Extension for Single-Precision Floating-Point
"D" Standard Extension for Double-Precision Floating-Point
"Q" Standard Extension for Quard-Precision Floating-point
"C" Standard Extension for Compressed Instruction
"G" combination of I, M, A, F and D.

ilp32/ilp32f/ilp32d    int-32bits    long-32bits    pointer-32bits
lp64/lp64f/lp64d      int-32bits    long-64bits    pointer-64bits

the vexrisc full project implement riscv on arty a7 35t, include tool-chain compile and using intellij IDE build riscv project and internal usb jtag debugging may help you
https://fatalfeel.blogspot.com/2013/12/risc-v-on-arty-a7-35t.html

and maybe you want to try linux on riscv, it's base on vexrisc
https://github.com/SpinalHDL/SaxonSoc